# how to implement assembler program

Tags: python, assembly, mips, variable-assignment

I have a simple assignment that is to program an assembler that can assemble 15 mips instructions (add, addi and, or, ori, nor, sll, slt, beq, lw, sw, sub, jal, jr, andi)
& i decided to program it with python as it is little easy language, my algorithm is to ask the user to enter the operation then the operands each in once, then the output machine code will be available in file.txt...using only if conditions as i am beginner & don't know alot about python,, does anyone suggest me a better algorithm for implementing this assembler using if conditions & i/o files in python?

```
inst = raw_input("enter your instruction operation:")

if ((inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'd' and inst[2] == 'd') or (inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'n' and inst[2] == 'd') or (inst[0] == 'o' and inst[1] == 'r') or (inst[0] == 'n' and inst[1] == 'o' and inst[2] == 'r') or (inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'u' and inst[2] == 'b') or (inst[0] == 'j' and inst[1] == 'r') or (inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'l' and inst[2] == 'l') or(inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'l' and inst[2] == 't')):
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        Rs = input("enter the destination operand:")
        rs = 
        opcode = '000000'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
elif (inst[0] == 'l' and inst[1] == 'w'):
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '100011'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode) + '\n')
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'w':
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '101011'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 'j' and inst[1] == 'a' and inst[2] == 'l':
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '000011'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 'b' and inst[1] == 'e' and inst[2] == 'q':
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '000100'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'n' and inst[2] == 'd'and inst[3] == 'i':
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '001100'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 'o' and inst[1] == 'r' and inst[2] == 'i':
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '001101'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'd' and inst[2] == 'd'and inst[3] == 'i':
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '001000'
        Mc_file.write('Opcode =' + str(opcode))
        Mc_file.close()
else:
    print "Not supported operation!"
```

Comment: "little easy language" seems to be the understatement of the year...

Comment: You said here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288313/assembler-implmentation) that your assignment was due withing 36 hours. Is this still the same assignment or another one? If it is the same, please post some of the effort you have invested (some code) and somebody will surely help you.

Comment: @hyperboreus yes you are right, but the deadline delayed , to sunday 11:59 PM , here is the code that converts only the operation part of the instruction:

Comment: sorry it seems that i cannt post the code here becuase i have no enough reputations!

Comment: i have edited the post & the code shown is supposed to translate the operation part of the instruction to the actual 6 bits opcode in machine language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your whole condition tree (excluding the first condition, as I doubt that `and` and `or` have the same opcode, can be reduced to this:

```
trans = {'lw': '100011',
    'sw': '101011',
    'jal': '000011',
    'beq': '000100',
    'andi': '001100',
    'ori': '001101',
    'addi': '00100'}

with open ('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    try: f.write (trans [inst] )
    except KeyError: print ('Operation not supported')
```

Comment: that's awesome i'm trying to understand the condition but how can i apply this to add $1 $2 $3

Answer (score 3):

Here's a "simple, but powerful" assembler for the 6502, written by David Beazley:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# asm6502.py

"""
A simple but powerful 6502 assembler

Author : David Beazley (http://www.dabeaz.com)
Copyright (C) 2010

Parses assembly language of the following form:

var=value               ; Variable assignment

label:   OP ADDR        ; Labeled opcode and address
         OP ADDR        ; Opcode and address

Addressing modes are as follows:

         #value         ; immediate mode (8-bit value)
         %value         ; zero-page mode
         %value,X       ; zero-page X indexed
         %value,Y       ; zero-page Y indexed
         value          ; absolute
         value,X        ; absolute Y indexed
         value,Y        ; absolute Y indexed
         [value]        ; indirect
         [value,X]      ; indirect, X indexed
         [value,Y]      ; indirect, Y indexed

values and labels can be any Python expression, but the final value must
evaluate to an integer value.   Use a numeric label to set the memory
location of instructions to follow.
"""

from collections import Callable
import re

# Exception used for errors
class AssemblyError(Exception): pass

# Functions used in the creation of object code (used in the table below)
def VALUE_L(pc, value):
    return value & 0xff

def VALUE_H(pc, value):
    return (value & 0xff00) >> 8

def RELATIVE_ADDR(pc, value):
    offset = value - (pc + 2)
    return offset & 0xff

# Table of 6502 opcodes and supported addressing modes
opcodes_6502 = {
    'DATA' : {
        'immed' :      [VALUE_L],
        },
    'ADC' : {
        'immed' :      [0x69, VALUE_L],
        'zerop' :      [0x65, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0x75, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0x6D, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0x7D, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_y' :      [0x79, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'indirect_x' : [0x61, VALUE_L],
        'indirect_y' : [0x71, VALUE_L],
        },
    'AND' : {
        'immed' :      [0x29, VALUE_L],
        'zerop' :      [0x25, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0x35, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0x2D, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0x3D, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_y' :      [0x39, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'indirect_x' : [0x21, VALUE_L],
        'indirect_y' : [0x31, VALUE_L],
        },
    'ASL' : {
        'accum' :      [0x0a],
        'zerop' :      [0x06, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0x16, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0x0e, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0x1e, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    'BIT' : {
        'zerop' :      [0x24, VALUE_L],
        'abs'   :      [0x2c, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
       },
    'BPL' : {
        'immed' :      [0x10, VALUE_L],
        'abs'   :      [0x10, RELATIVE_ADDR],
        },
    'BMI' : {
        'immed' :      [0x30, VALUE_L],
        'abs'   :      [0x30, RELATIVE_ADDR],
        },
    'BVC' : {
        'immed' :      [0x50, VALUE_L],
        'abs'   :      [0x50, RELATIVE_ADDR],
        },
    'BVS' : {
        'immed' :      [0x70, VALUE_L],
        'abs'   :      [0x70, RELATIVE_ADDR],
        },
    'BCC' : {
        'immed' :      [0x90, VALUE_L],
        'abs'   :      [0x90, RELATIVE_ADDR],
        },
    'BCS' : {
        'immed' :      [0xb0, VALUE_L],
        'abs'   :      [0xb0, RELATIVE_ADDR],
        },
    'BNE' : {
        'immed' :      [0xd0, VALUE_L],
        'abs'   :      [0xd0, RELATIVE_ADDR],
        },
    'BEQ' : {
        'immed' :      [0xf0, VALUE_L],
        'abs'   :      [0xf0, RELATIVE_ADDR],
        },
    'BRK' : {
        'accum' :      [0x00],
        'immed' :      [0x00, VALUE_L],
        },
    'CMP' : {
        'immed' :      [0xc9, VALUE_L],
        'zerop' :      [0xc5, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0xd5, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0xcD, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0xdD, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_y' :      [0xd9, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'indirect_x' : [0xc1, VALUE_L],
        'indirect_y' : [0xd1, VALUE_L],
        },
    'CPX' : {
        'immed' :      [0xe0, VALUE_L],
        'zerop' :      [0xe4, VALUE_L],
        'abs'   :      [0xec, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    'CPY' : {
        'immed' :      [0xc0, VALUE_L],
        'zerop' :      [0xc4, VALUE_L],
        'abs'   :      [0xcc, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    'DEC' : {
        'zerop' :      [0xc6, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0xd6, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0xce, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0xde, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    'EOR' : {
        'immed' :      [0x49, VALUE_L],
        'zerop' :      [0x45, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0x55, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0x4D, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0x5D, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_y' :      [0x59, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'indirect_x' : [0x41, VALUE_L],
        'indirect_y' : [0x51, VALUE_L],
        },
    'CLC' : {
        'accum' :      [0x18],
        },
    'SEC' : {
        'accum' :      [0x38],
        },
    'CLI' : {
        'accum' :      [0x58],
        },
    'SEI' : {
        'accum' :      [0x78],
        },
    'CLV' : {
        'accum' :      [0xb8],
        },
    'CLD' : {
        'accum' :      [0xd8],
        },
    'SED' : {
        'accum' :      [0xf8],
        },
    'INC' : {
        'zerop' :      [0xe6, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0xf6, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0xee, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0xfe, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    'JMP' : {
        'abs' :        [0x4c, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'indirect' :   [0x6c, VALUE_L, VALUE_H]
        },
    'JSR' : {
        'abs' :        [0x20, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    'LDA' : {
        'immed' :      [0xA9, VALUE_L],
        'zerop' :      [0xA5, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0xB5, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0xAD, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0xBD, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_y' :      [0xB9, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'indirect_x' : [0xA1, VALUE_L],
        'indirect_y' : [0xB1, VALUE_L],
        },
    'LDX' : {
        'immed' :      [0xa2, VALUE_L],
        'zerop' :      [0xa6, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_y' :    [0xb6, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0xae, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_y' :      [0xbe, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    'LDY' : { 
        'immed' :      [0xa0, VALUE_L],
        'zerop' :      [0xa4, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0xb4, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0xac, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0xbc, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    'LSR' : {
        'accum' :      [0x4a],
        'zerop' :      [0x46, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0x56, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0x4e, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0x5e, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    'NOP' : {
        'accum' :      [0xea],
        },
    'ORA' : {
        'immed' :      [0x09, VALUE_L],
        'zerop' :      [0x05, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0x15, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0x0D, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0x1D, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_y' :      [0x19, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'indirect_x' : [0x01, VALUE_L],
        'indirect_y' : [0x11, VALUE_L],
        },
    'TAX' : {
        'accum' :      [0xaa],
        },
    'TXA' : {
        'accum' :      [0x8a],
        },
    'DEX' : {
        'accum' :      [0xca],
        },
    'INX' : {
        'accum' :      [0xe8],
        },
    'TAY' : {
        'accum' :      [0xa8],
        },
    'TYA' : {
        'accum' :      [0x98],
        },
    'DEY' : {
        'accum' :      [0x88],
        },
    'INY' : {
        'accum' :      [0xc8],
        },
    'ROL' : {
        'accum' :      [0x2a],
        'zerop' :      [0x26, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0x36, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0x2e, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0x3e, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    'ROR' : {
        'accum' :      [0x6a],
        'zerop' :      [0x66, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0x76, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0x6e, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0x7e, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    'RTI' : {
        'accum' :      [0x40],
        },
    'RTS' : {
        'accum' :      [0x60],
        },
    'SBC' : {
        'immed' :      [0xe9, VALUE_L],
        'zerop' :      [0xe5, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0xf5, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0xeD, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0xfD, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_y' :      [0xf9, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'indirect_x' : [0xe1, VALUE_L],
        'indirect_y' : [0xf1, VALUE_L],
        },
    'STA' : {
        'zerop' :      [0x85, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0x95, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0x8D, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_x' :      [0x9D, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'abs_y' :      [0x99, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        'indirect_x' : [0x81, VALUE_L],
        'indirect_y' : [0x91, VALUE_L],
        },
    'TXS' : {
        'accum' :      [0x9a],
        },
    'TSX' : {
        'accum' :      [0xba],
        },
    'PHA' : {
        'accum' :      [0x48],
        },
    'PLA' : {
        'accum' :      [0x68],
        },
    'PHP' : {
        'accum' :      [0x08],
        },
    'PLP' : {
        'accum' :      [0x28],
        },
    'STX' : {
        'zerop' :      [0x86, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_y' :    [0x96, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0x8e, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    'STY' : {
        'zerop' :      [0x84, VALUE_L],
        'zerop_x' :    [0x94, VALUE_L],
        'abs' :        [0x8c, VALUE_L, VALUE_H],
        },
    }

# Parse address modes for various 6502 instructions
def parse_address_mode(mode):
    # Accumulator or implicit. Example: INC
    if not mode or mode == 'A':    return ("accum","0")  

    # Immediate value. Example : LDA #13  
    if mode.startswith("#"):       return ("immed", mode[1:]) 

    # Strip unneeded whitespace if not an immediate value
    mode = mode.replace(' ','')

    # Zero-page address with indexing. Example : LDA %25, X
    if mode.startswith("%"):
        if mode.endswith(",X"):    return ("zerop_x", mode[1:-2])
        elif mode.endswith(",Y"):  return ("zerop_y", mode[1:-2])
        else:                      return ("zerop", mode[1:])

    # Indirect addressing.Example : LDA [0xFF00, X]
    if mode.startswith("["):   
        if mode.endswith(",X]"):   return ("indirect_x", mode[1:-3])
        elif mode.endswith(",Y]"): return ("indirect_y",mode[1:-3])
        elif mode.endswith("]"):   return ("indirect", mode[1:-1])

    # Absolute address, with indexing. Example : LDA 0xFF00, X
    if mode.endswith(",X"):        return ("abs_x",mode[:-2])
    elif mode.endswith(",Y"):      return ("abs_y",mode[:-2])
    else:                          return ("abs",mode)

# Parse an opcode line into intermediate object code. Returns a tuple
# (value, objcode) where value is a string to be evaluated in the 2nd pass
def parse_opcode(line):
    fields = line.split(None,1)
    opcode = fields[0]
    arg = fields[1] if len(fields) == 2 else ""
    mode,value = parse_address_mode(arg)
    opcodemodes = opcodes_6502.get(opcode)
    if not opcodemodes:
        raise AssemblyError("Unknown opcode '%s'" % opcode)
    objcode = opcodemodes.get(mode)
    if not objcode:
        raise AssemblyError("Invalid addressing mode '%s' for opcode %s" % (arg,opcode))
    return (value,list(objcode))

# Takes a sequence of lines and strip comments and blanks
def strip_lines(lines):
    for line in lines:
        comment_index = line.find(";")
        if comment_index >= 0:
            line = line[:comment_index]
        line = line.strip()
        yield line

assign_pat = re.compile(r'(\s*)([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(\s*=)')

# Parse lines into intermediate object code
def parse_lines(lines,symbols):
    for lineno,line in enumerate(lines,1):
        if assign_pat.match(line):
            exec(line,symbols)
        else:
            label, *colon, statement = line.rpartition(":")
            try:
                yield lineno, label, parse_opcode(statement) if statement else (None,None)
            except AssemblyError as e:
                print("{0:4d} : Error : {1}".format(lineno,e))

# Assemble a sequence of lines into binary
def assemble_6502(lines,pc=0):
    objcode = []
    symbols = {}
    symbols['HIGH'] = lambda x : (x & 0xff00) >> 8
    symbols['LOW'] = lambda x : x & 0xff

    # Pass 1 : Parse instructions and create intermediate code
    for lineno, label, (value, icode) in parse_lines(lines,symbols):
        # Try to evaluate numeric labels and set the PC
        if label:
            try:
                pc = int(eval(label,symbols))
            except (ValueError,NameError):
                symbols[label] = pc

        # Store the resulting objcode for later expansion
        if icode:
            objcode.append((lineno,pc,value,icode))
            pc += len(icode)

    # Pass 2 : Create final object code by evaluating expressions
    execode = []
    for lineno, pc, value, icode in objcode:
        # Evaluate the value string
        try:
            symbols['PC'] = pc
            realvalue = eval(value,symbols)
            if isinstance(realvalue,str):
                realvalue = ord(realvalue) & 0xff
            if not isinstance(realvalue, int):
                raise TypeError("Integer expected in {0}".format(value))
        except Exception as e:
            print("{0:4d} : Error : {1}".format(lineno,e),file=sys.stderr)
            realvalue = 0
        ecode = [op(pc,realvalue) if isinstance(op,Callable) else op
                 for op in icode]
        execode.append((lineno,pc,ecode))
    return execode

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage %s infile.asm" % sys.argv[0],file=sys.stderr)
        raise SystemExit(1)
    lines = strip_lines(open(sys.argv[1]))
    if 0:
        for lineno, pc, opcode in assemble_6502(lines):
            print("%04x : " % pc, end="")
            print(*(format(op,"02x") for op in opcode))
    if 1:
        # OSI monitor format
        first = 0
        lastpc = -1
        for lineno, pc, opcode in assemble_6502(lines):
            if not first:
                first = pc
            if lastpc != pc:
                print(".%04X/" % pc,end="")
            for op in opcode:
                print("%02X" % op)
            lastpc = pc + len(opcode)
        print(".00FB/00")
```

There is also [a simple, two-pass 6502 assembler](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/fa13/proj/04/assembler.py) that is used by Berkeley for studying processor design (also implemented in a single Python file), which has [excellent documentation](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/fa13/proj/04/) as well.

Comment: great but as i said in the question its a simple MIPS  instructions set assembler. the one you posted is beyond the requirements of the assignment.

Comment: @cMinor How dare you? OP is asking you to do his assignment, and you do not fully comply with his requirements. Ts, ts, ts ;)

Comment: It is just sample code, that OP can study to get some ideas, also we can not we full complete answer if OP does not show at least some work, right?

Comment: @cMinor My poiny exactely. Not only that OP showed no efforts of his own, but he complains about you not doing exactely what he needs...

Comment: @Amr saad - He actually posted two.